# Converting PHP array to vb.net Array

Tags: php, vb.net, arrays, loops

```
                for($reg3=0; $reg3<strlen($str); $reg3++)
                {
                    $reg0 = $str[$reg3];

                        switch($reg0)
                        {
                            case '0': $reg1[] = '0000'; break;
                            case '1': $reg1[] = '0001'; break;
                            case '2': $reg1[] = '0010'; break;
                            case '3': $reg1[] = '0011'; break;
                            case '4': $reg1[] = '0100'; break;
                            case '5': $reg1[] = '0101'; break;
                            case '6': $reg1[] = '0110'; break;
                            case '7': $reg1[] = '0111'; break;
                            case '8': $reg1[] = '1000'; break;
                            case '9': $reg1[] = '1001'; break;
                            case 'a': $reg1[] = '1010'; break;
                            case 'b': $reg1[] = '1011'; break;
                            case 'c': $reg1[] = '1100'; break;
                            case 'd': $reg1[] = '1101'; break;
                            case 'e': $reg1[] = '1110'; break;
                            case 'f': $reg1[] = '1111'; break;
                        }
                }

                $reg1 = join($reg1);
```

Comment: You can use `decbin(hexdec($reg0));` instead of big switch, but anyway, what is the question?

Comment: i wanted to convert this code to vb.net but what should i do with array length?..in php code array length is dynamic

Comment: is there a way to dynamically declare the size of an array in vb.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with a List, that way you can work dynamic.